# AngularJS custom orderBy from the same variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my view I am doing this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item.some_key}}
</div>
```

some_key variable has only 3 type of string output: "unsafe", "elevated" and "trace". I want to order output of items in this order: first all items which have unsafe, then "elevated" and at the end "trace" ... I can't do this in a simple orderBy filter ... How to achieve this?

Thanks for a help in advance!

Comment: create a custom filter ... see filter docs ... or map the data in controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a custom `orderBy`

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: statusEvent">
    {{item.some_key}}
</div>

$scope.statusEvent = function(item) {
    if (item.some_key == "unsafe") return 0
    else if (item.some_key == "elevated") return 1
    else if (item.some_key == "trace") return 2
    else return 3
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies the issue a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom filter

```
var orders = {
  unsafe:0,
  elevated:1,
  trace:2
}
$scope.someKeyOrder = function(item){
  return orders[item.some_key];
}
```

and use it

```
ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: someKeyOrder"
```

Demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/4Tjsc8?p=preview